# Prove or disprove: $A × B = B × A$ if and only if $A = B.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Here's what I know:

-Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets.
-I must use an if-and-only-if template, which contains a set equality template inside one half of it.

However, I'm having trouble locating where I would need to put the set equality template. Here's the outline I currently have.

It appears that I'm very weak in starting proofs, but I can typically get control of them once I get started. Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty sets.
Proof.
[=>] Suppose $A × B = B × A.$ 
......Set equality proof here possible?
Therefore $A = B$.
[<=]
On the other hand, suppose $A = B$.
......Or here?
Therefore $A × B = B × A.$

Comment: Let $(x,y)\in (A\times B)$ . What does that mean? Doesn't it lead you somewhere?

Comment: That means that $x ∈ A$ and $y ∈ B$.

I guess my main question is what part of the template do I need to show the set equality? Why aren't I supposed to for both, considering they both end in proving an equal set. What's the 'cheap' way to one of them?

Comment: for $\Rightarrow$ you started good, then suppose that $A \ne B$  and show that $A\times B \ne B \times A$ , you do that by finding element in  $A\times B $ that is not in  $B \times A $ . for $\Leftarrow$ just use definition of $\times$ . try to answer question yourself

Answer (score 3):

You need the hypothesis that both A and B are nonempty. Fix any $b\in B$. Suppose $A\times B=B\times A$, and take $x\in A$. Then $(x,b)\in A\times B=B\times A$, so $x\in B$. The converse inclusion is analogous.

Now, if $A=B$, then $A\times B= A\times A=B\times A$.